# Create Drawable For Single Color

Tags: android

I have a button that when clicked, I would like the color of the text to change from white to yellow. I created a selector XML file in my drawable folder. My question is, I don't know how to set the color of my text when state_pressed is true. I tried using hexadecimals but kept getting the following error:

```
<item> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable
```

I assume the color has to come from my drawable folder? I finally found this solution but am limited to the amount of colors I can use

```
<item
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@android:color/holo_blue_light">
</item>
```

How can I solve this? Can I create separate XML file in my drawable folder with just one color that I can reference? If so, how do I do this? Or is there a simpler solution? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> bg_color_white.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

          <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />

</shape>
```

Answer (score 5):

First create a colors.xml resource file in your app/resource/values for example like this one below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="gray">#D2D2D2</color>
    <color name="dark_gray">#ff838383</color>
    <color name="transparent_black">#1A000000</color>
</resources>
```

Then you can use the colors defined in colors.xml to create your selector.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:color="@color/gray" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/dark_gray" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/dark_gray" />
    <item android:color="@color/transparent_black" />
</selector>
```

Place the xml in a file at res/drawable folder i.e. res/drawable/button_text_color.xml. Then just set the drawable as text color in your button:

```
android:textColor="@drawable/button_text_color"
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an XML file "myCustomDrawable" in your Drawable folder as follows:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/lightPurple"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Where "deepPurple" and "lightPurple" are defined in ...values/colors.xml as:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name = "deepPurple">#673AB7</color>
    <color name = "lightPurple">#D1C4E9</color>
</resources>
```

Then simply assign the Drawable file to your button in your activity's layout as:

```html
<Button 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  ... 
  ... 
  android:textColor="@drawable/myCustomDrawable" 
  ... 
  .../>
```

Answer (score 1):

I still kept getting the same error but the responses helped me figure it out. The issue is the syntax in my selector:

```
<item
android:state_pressed="true"
android:drawable="@android:color/holo_blue_light"> </item>
```

The syntax for the color HAD to begin with android:drawable=, otherwise I kept getting the same error over and over. For example, if I used:

```
 android:color="@color/gray"
```

or

```
<solid android:color="@color/gray" />
```

It kept producing this error:

```
<item> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable
```

So, like it was suggested, I created an XML file called colors in my values folder and created a color that I wanted to use:

```
<resources>
<color name = "light_blue">#33b5e5</color>
</resources>
```

I was then able to use it in my selector file as follows:

```
android:drawable="@color/light_blue""
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is a sample of what is known as a selector for drawable.

Put it under your /drawable folder.

Where you see android:state_pressed="true" this is what will define what happens when button is pressed. This is the color you set to yellow.

state_focused="true" is when a finger is pressing the button but not letting go therefore it has focus. You may want to change the color to yellow here.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
     <item android:state_pressed="true" >
         <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
             <corners android:radius="3dip" />
             <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#39678c" />
             <gradient android:angle="-90" android:startColor="#39678c" android:endColor="#39678c"  />    
             <size android:width="75dp" android:height="25dp"/>

         </shape>
     </item>
    <item android:state_focused="true">
         <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
             <corners android:radius="8dip" />
             <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#696969" />
             <solid android:color="#696969"/>  
             <size android:width="75dp" android:height="25dp"/>     
         </shape>
     </item>  
    <item >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
             <corners android:radius="8dip" />
             <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#39678c" />
             <gradient android:angle="-90" android:startColor="#39678c" android:endColor="#39678c" />  
             <size android:width="75dp" android:height="10dp"/>          
         </shape>
     </item>
    </selector>
```

Comment: I am assuming that you don't want to color to stay yellow after the user let's go of the button. But if you want the color to stay yellow after the user let's go. You may want to use something else.